# Tcl: information about currently executed interpreter

Tags: tcl

I am using TCL embedeed in third party software. I am trying to get info what is the name\path of main interpreter used by third party software and also information if there exist some slave interpreters.
I can find what executable is used to run interpreter `info nameofexecutable` but don't know how to get path to main interpreter being executed.

Comment: The documentation says `info nameofexecutable` returns a full path name. Is it not for you?

Comment: If you're referring to the `interp` command... *Also, there is no global name by which one can refer to the first interpreter created in an application.*

Comment: Tcl is not just avaliable as an executable (app) but also a library. Tcl is embeddable long before Lua was invented. So if you're trying to find name/path on your hard disk of the interpreter it could just be the software itself instead of a separate program. Because apart from being available as a program tcl is also available simply as C code that you can add to your own program.

Comment: `I can find what executable is used to run interpreter` I think this shows your confusion. That executable probably not only **run** your interpreter but **IS** the interpreter itself (because, again, the interpreter is also available as C code)

Answer (score 0):

The root/ultimate master interpreter of a tree of interpreters has an empty name. The overall collection of interpreters in an application is technically a forest (and the trees in the forest can't normally see each other at all). These are not usually useful facts.

The `tclsh` program only makes one interpreter by default (per thread), and the `wish` program makes two on some platforms (one of which handles the other end of the fake console, and which can be manipulated via the `console` command). When Tcl is embedded in a C or C++ program, there can be many (one tree per call to `Tcl_CreateInterp()`) but they don't have any cross-references unless code makes them.

Comment: I found `wish` in the parent software dir, but guess (like @slebetman comment above) that **.exe** is itself interpreter and create **tcl objects**

Comment: "Name of interpreter" can mean many very specific things. Why do you need it?